# Открытие страниц в Wordpress в модальном окне точно как в Pinterest?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Вроде как, надо начинать с логики сайта в `function.php`. Затем, связать *это* через скрипт с аякс. Что делать дальше я не понимаю.

Comment: "сайт" http://cg91812-wordpress-3.tw1.ru/

Comment: Опишите проблему , ошибки ,ваши действия, и каков должен быть результат.
Ясновидцев тут нет

Comment: Грубо говоря, меня нужно ткнуть носом в готовое решение, или хоть не совсем готовое Так как, я понимаю работу только html и css в общем, и что связанно с реализацией такого модального окна я толком ничего не понимаю

Comment: Может можно сделать через iframe: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/3j7dLecf/   А в href подставлять адресную строку поста...Но как..через id поста? Прошу прощения,  ничего не понимаю просто

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Подключите bootstrap.js
2. Используйте код

   ```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Large modal</button>

   <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
            Some Text or HTML
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   ```

Источник - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/
Есть описание на русском языке http://bootstrap-3.ru/javascript.php

Comment: А при скачивании архива bootstrap.js, мне указывать в содержании архива только Modals можно? Или если скачаю весь плагин, то на работу сайта полная версия не повлияет?

Comment: @user216356 - Вам нужен файл bootstrap.js. Файл повлиять на работу сайта не должен.

Comment: Все сделал Но использовать этот вышенаписанный код мне кажется сложно, потому что сайт на Вордпресс и посты в  шаблоне расположены так же, как и в на сайте пинтерест У каждого поста же свой адрес Где мне именно использовать этот код В каком файле php Вордпресса?

Comment: @user216356 - Использовать код не сложно, посмотрите это видео, Вы сможете понять принцип подключения модального окна в wordpress [Видео настройки модального окна](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBA8vr6Zyqo)

Comment: @user216356 - вот конкретный ответ на Ваш вопрос - "Как открывать посты в модальном окне Bootstrap" [ссылка](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95661/open-wordpress-posts-in-bootstrap-modal)